# Acoustic echo cancellation in Java

Tags: java, echo, signal-processing, javasound, cancellation

I'm implementing a VOIP application that uses pure Java. There is an echo problem that occurs when users do not use headsets (mostly on laptops with built-in microphones).

**What currently happens**

The nuts and bolts of the VOIP application is just the plain datalines of Java's media framework. Essentially, I'd like to perform some digital signal processing on audio data before I write it to the speaker for output.

```
  public synchronized void addAudioData(byte[] ayAudioData)
  {
    m_oBuffer.enqueue(ayAudioData);
    this.notify();
  }
```

As you can see the audio data arrives and is enqueued in a buffer. This is to cater for dodgy connections and to allow for different packet sizes. It also means I have access to as much audio data as I need for any fancy DSP operations before I play the audio data to the speaker line.

I've managed one echo canceller that does work, however it requires a lot of interactive user input and I'd like to have an automatic echo canceller.

**Manual echo canceller**

```
public static byte[] removeEcho(int iDelaySamples, float fDecay, byte[] aySamples)
  {
    m_awDelayBuffer = new short[iDelaySamples];
    m_aySamples = new byte[aySamples.length];
    m_fDecay = (float) fDecay;
    System.out.println("Removing echo");
    m_iDelayIndex = 0;

    System.out.println("Sample length:\t" + aySamples.length);
    for (int i = 0; i < aySamples.length; i += 2)
    {
      // update the sample
      short wOldSample = getSample(aySamples, i);

      // remove the echo
      short wNewSample = (short) (wOldSample - fDecay * m_awDelayBuffer[m_iDelayIndex]);
      setSample(m_aySamples, i, wNewSample);

      // update the delay buffer
      m_awDelayBuffer[m_iDelayIndex] = wNewSample;
      m_iDelayIndex++;

      if (m_iDelayIndex == m_awDelayBuffer.length)
      {
        m_iDelayIndex = 0;
      }
    }

    return m_aySamples;
  }
```

**Adaptive filters**

I've read that [adaptive filters](http://www.developer.com/java/other/article.php/3549991/Adaptive-Filtering-in-Java-Getting-Started.htm) are the way to go. Specifically, a Least Mean Squares filter. However, I'm stuck. Most sample code for the above are in C and C++ and they don't translate well into Java.

Does anyone have advice on how to implement them in Java? Any other ideas would also be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I found this Acoustic Echo Cancellation guide very, very helpful so far:

http://www.andreadrian.de/echo_cancel/index.html

Answer (score 5):

It's been ages! Hope this is even the right class, but there you go:

```
/**
 * This filter performs a pre-whitening Normalised Least Means Square on an
 * array of bytes. This does the actual echo cancelling.
 * 
 * Echo cancellation occurs with the following formula:
 * 
 * e = d - X' * W
 * 
 * e represents the echo-free signal. d represents the actual microphone signal
 * with the echo. X' is the transpose of the loudspeaker signal. W is an array
 * of adaptive weights.
 * 
 */
public class cNormalisedLeastMeansSquareFilter
  implements IFilter
{
  private byte[] m_ayEchoFreeSignal;// e
  private byte[] m_ayEchoSignal;// d
  private byte[] m_ayTransposeOfSpeakerSignal;// X'
  private double[] m_adWeights;// W

  /**
   * The transpose and the weights need to be updated before applying the filter
   * to an echo signal again.
   * 
   * @param ayEchoSignal
   * @param ayTransposeOfSpeakerSignal
   * @param adWeights
   */
  public cNormalisedLeastMeansSquareFilter(byte[] ayEchoSignal, byte[] ayTransposeOfSpeakerSignal, double[] adWeights)
  {
    m_ayEchoSignal = ayEchoSignal;
    m_ayTransposeOfSpeakerSignal = ayTransposeOfSpeakerSignal;
    m_adWeights = adWeights;
  }

  @Override
  public byte[] applyFilter(byte[] ayAudioBytes)
  {
    // e = d - X' * W
    m_ayEchoFreeSignal = new byte[ayAudioBytes.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < m_ayEchoFreeSignal.length; ++i)
    {
      m_ayEchoFreeSignal[i] = (byte) (m_ayEchoSignal[i] - m_ayTransposeOfSpeakerSignal[i] * m_adWeights[i]);
    }
    return m_ayEchoFreeSignal;
  }
```

Comment: You would have been better off adding this code to your original answer than posting a new answer.

Comment: How do I integrate this piece of code with my existing project in which I am encoding a raw file to PCM data and then the PCM file is getting encoded to .spx file. I am using jspeex.jar for this.

Answer (score 4):

In case anyone is interested, I managed to build a fair, working echo canceller by basically converting the [Acoustic Echo Cancellation](http://www.andreadrian.de/echo_cancel/draft-aec-03.txt) method [mentioned by Paul R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3403152/acoustic-echo-cancellation-in-java/3403198#3403198) that uses a Normalised Least Means Square algorithm and a few filters from C into Java. The JNI route is probably still a better way to go, but I like sticking to pure Java if at all possible. By seeing how their filters work and reading up a great deal on filters on [DSP Tutor](http://www.dsptutor.freeuk.com/), I managed to gain some control over how much noise gets removed and how to remove high frequencies, etc.

Some tips:

1. Keep in mind what you remove from where. I had to switch this around a few times.
2. The most important variable of this method is the convergence rate. This is the variable called Stepsize in the above link's code.
3. I took the individual components one at a time, figured out what they did, built them and tested them separately. For example, I took the Double Talk Detector and tested it to ensure that it worked. Then I took the filters one by one and tested them on audio files to ensure that they worked, then I took the normalised least means square part and tested it before putting it all together.

Hope this helps someone else!

Answer (score 4):

Use the [Speex](http://www.speex.org/) [AEC](http://www.speex.org/docs/manual/speex-manual/node7.html#SECTION00740000000000000000). It's open source, it's written in C (use it with JNI), and it works.
I've successfully used it in 2 different VoIP applications and it gets most of the echo cancelled.

Comment: hi can u please  guide me how to cancel echo .i am struggling to get it work

Comment: You can contact me in the email written in my profile. This is not something to summarize in one post.

Comment: @SirKnigget How do I install Speex?

Answer (score 1):

This is a very complex area and to get a usable AEC solution working you'll need to do quite a bit of R&D. All the good AECs are proprietary, and there's a *lot* more to echo cancellation than just implementing an adaptive filter such as LMS. I suggest you develop your echo cancellation algorithm initially using MATLAB (or Octave) - when you have something that appears to work reasonably well with "real world" telecomms then you can implement the algorithm in C and test/evaluate it in real-time. Once this is working you can use JNI to call the C implementation from Java.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've been trying to avoid using JNI but getting desperate enough to try anything.

Comment: You may well find that you need to do platform-specific stuff in your AEC, e.g. low level OS/audio API calls, so it might as well be C + JNI.